# Hall effect placement on axial flux BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

recently i was given a project regarding flywheel energy storage. One of the main component of my project is a axial flux BLDC. I have been searching around and i couldnt find a good source regarding hall sensor placement. I know it should be placed 120 electrical degrees apart, but the tricky thing is about the first sensor placement where it should transition from low to high at the positive zero crossing of the back EMF. In my motor configuration, where should i place the sensors? (8 poles, 6 coils)

Any help is greatly appreciated

[image: view of the coil]